# Why doesn't my IF ELSE work?

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

It's a simple script I wrote, nothing fancy at all

```
@echo off

echo 1 = stream1 source
echo 2 = stream1 high
echo 3 = stream1 medium
echo 4 = stream1 low
echo 5 = stream2 source
echo 6 = stream2 high
echo 7 = stream2 medium
echo 8 = stream2 low

set /p id="Enter ID: "

IF %id% == 1 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 source
) ELSE IF %id% == 2 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
) ELSE IF %id% == 3 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 medium
) ELSE IF %id% == 4 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 low
) ELSE IF %id% == 5 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 source
) ELSE IF %id% == 6 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 high
) ELSE IF %id% == 7 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 medium
) ELSE IF %id% == 8 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
) ELSE (
echo ..............
echo 1 = source
echo 2 = high
echo 3 = medium
echo 4 = low

set /p quality="Enter ID: "

    IF %quality% == 1 (
        set hq="source"
    ) ELSE IF %quality% == 2 (
        set hq="high"
    ) ELSE IF %quality% == 3 (
        set hq="medium"
    ) ELSE IF %quality% == 4 (
        set hq="low"
    ) ELSE (
        set hq="source"
    )
    set link=twitch.tv/%id% %hq%
)

Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe %link%

echo %link%

pause
```

What it does is ask for a number 1-8, if it's 1-8 it'll run the program livestream.exe with command line stream1 source, stream2 source, etc depending on what the user input.

If it's not 1-8, then the program asks for the quality, so source/high/medium/low.

For example, if they put in 1, then the command that'll finally be run is

```
Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe stream1 source
```

If 2,

```
Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe stream1 high
```

etc

If they put in for example asdfasdf

then put in high, then the final will be

```
Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe asdfasdf high
```

It works if i remove the stuff inside the final else condition, but otherwise it doesn't :(

The error I'm getting is

```
( was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Remove `@echo off` for debugging!! then you will see what each variable is expanded to...

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, `batch` wasn't a powerful language. 
I faced same problem as you did, so I realized that the brackets need to be in that exact format otherwise it doesn’t work at all. Even putting brackets around the `if` part of the statement will stop the script from working as expected.

You can use `choice` statement, a simple statement that determine user input.

```
@echo off


:point_one
echo 1 = stream1 source
echo 2 = stream1 high
echo 3 = stream1 medium
echo 4 = stream1 low
echo 5 = stream2 source
echo 6 = stream2 high
echo 7 = stream2 medium
echo 8 = stream2 low

set /a id = 0

choice /c:123456789 /m "Enter ID: " /n

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 source
    set /a id = 1
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
    set /a id = 2
) 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 3 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 medium
    set /a id = 3
) 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 4 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 low
    set /a id = 4
) 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 5 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 source
    set /a id = 5
) 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 6 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 high
    set /a id = 6
) 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 7 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 medium
    set /a id = 7
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 8 (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
    set /a id = 8
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 9 (
    goto point_two
)

goto point_three


:point_two
echo ..............
echo 1 = source
echo 2 = high
echo 3 = medium
echo 4 = low

choice /c:12345678 /m "Enter ID: " /n

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
    set hq="source"
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 (
    set hq="high"
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 3 (
    set hq="medium"
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 4 (
    set hq="low"
) 
ELSE set hq="source"

set link=twitch.tv/%id% %hq%

goto point three


:point_three

Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe %link%

echo %link%

pause >nul
```

I still don't understand why you add an `else` statement at the end. I mean why not add an extra selection for user to choose whether they want to go to `:point_two`

Comment: Thank you so much. That's almost perfect. however what I need to be able to do is For the first part, when it asks for ID, you should be able to type stuff in. So for example, if I put in testasdf as the input for first part, it will take that, combined with what you choose in 2nd place, and use that.

Comment: so do you mean user will go through both `:point_one` and `:point_two`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you fell into the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082), but you can easily avoid it by simplifying your code (it is unneccessary complex). Something like:

```
@echo off
set hq=

echo 1 = stream1 source
echo 2 = stream1 high
echo 3 = stream1 medium
echo 4 = stream1 low
echo 5 = stream2 source
echo 6 = stream2 high
echo 7 = stream2 medium
echo 8 = stream2 low

set link=none
set /p id=Enter ID:
IF "%id%"=="1" set link=twitch.tv/stream1 source
IF "%id%"=="2" set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
IF "%id%"=="3" set link=twitch.tv/stream1 medium
IF "%id%"=="4" set link=twitch.tv/stream1 low
IF "%id%"=="5" set link=twitch.tv/stream2 source
IF "%id%"=="6" set link=twitch.tv/stream2 high
IF "%id%"=="7" set link=twitch.tv/stream2 medium
IF "%id%"=="8" set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high

if "%link%" neq "none" goto :skip
cls
echo ..............
echo 1 = source
echo 2 = high
echo 3 = medium
echo 4 = low
echo ..............
set /p quality=Enter ID:
IF "%quality%"=="1" set hq="source"
IF "%quality%"=="2" set hq="high"
IF "%quality%"=="3" set hq="medium"
IF "%quality%"=="4" set hq="low"
REM are you sure, you want the quotes in %hq% ?

:skip
set param=twitch.tv/%link% %hq%
Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe %param%
echo %param%
pause
```

You had a logical quirk with your parameters in the last few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

echo 1 = stream1 source
echo 2 = stream1 high
echo 3 = stream1 medium
echo 4 = stream1 low
echo 5 = stream2 source
echo 6 = stream2 high
echo 7 = stream2 medium
echo 8 = stream2 low

set /p id=Enter ID:
::point one
IF "%id%"=="1" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 source
) 
IF "%id%"=="2" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
) 
IF "%id%"=="3" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 medium
) 
IF "%id%"=="4" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 low
) 
IF "%id%"=="5" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 source
) 
IF "%id%"=="6" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 high
) 
IF "%id%"=="7" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream2 medium
)
IF "%id%"=="8" (
    set link=twitch.tv/stream1 high
)
::point one end
cls
echo ..............
echo 1 = source
echo 2 = high
echo 3 = medium
echo 4 = low
echo ..............
set /p quality=Enter ID:
::point two begin
    IF "%quality%"=="1" (
        set hq="source"
    ) 
    IF "%quality%"=="2" (
        set hq="high"
    ) 
    IF "%quality%"=="3" (
        set hq="medium"
    ) 
    IF "%quality%"=="4" (
        set hq="low"
    )
    set link=twitch.tv/%id% %hq%
    ::point two end

Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe %link%

echo %link%

pause
```

Your IF-else syntax was incorrect (from the point which i labelled point one begin to point one end) the same goes for the points which i marked point two begin to point two end. The script should work properly now.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, my code works fine if i remove the parts starting from echo .......... to set link=twitch.tv/%id% %hq% and replace with something like set link=1. Also, for this I want it to ask for quality only if the id input is not numbers between 1 and 8

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is produced by the delayed expansion trap, as Stephan indicated in his answer: the `quality` variable is read *inside a code block*, so the `%quality%` expansion get the same value the variable had *before* the block. You need to change that expansion by `!quality!` and include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`at beginning in order to fix your error.

However, you should know that the [array concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type) is a method that programming languages use to process a series of elements in the same way. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store individual elements in the array; at same time, show the menu

set i=0
for %%a in ("stream1 source" "stream1 high" "stream1 medium" "stream1 low"
            "stream2 source" "stream2 high" "stream2 medium" "stream2 low") do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "option[!i!]=%%~a"
   echo !i! = %%~a
)

set /p id="Enter ID: "

if defined option[%id%] (

   set "link=twitch.tv/!option[%id%]!"

) else (

   echo ..............

   rem The same...
   set i=0
   for %%a in (source high medium low) do (
      set /A i+=1
      set "id[!i!]=%%a"
      echo !i! = %%a
   )

   set /p quality="Enter ID: "

   if defined id[!quality!] (

      rem Note that is not possible to nest expansions this way: set hq="!id[!quality!]!"
      for %%i in (!quality!) do set hq="!id[%%i]!"

   ) else (
      set hq="source"
   )
   set link=twitch.tv/!id! !hq!
)

Start C:\livestreamer\livestreamer.exe %link%

echo %link%

pause
```

For a further description on array management in Batch files, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).